# Confused by MOSFET pins

Tags: powermosfet

So here is a [MOSFET](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FDMS86183-D.pdf) that I'm planning to use for a 10A constant current source. Look at page 3 where where they've shown how a 1 sq. in. copper pad affects the RθJA. Pins 1-3 is the source, 4 is the gate and 5-8 with the larger pad is the drain. Why are the drain pins named as DF and DS and the Source as SF and SS? Arent they the same? Also why is there a think trace on S/DS? Also is that 1 sq. in. copper pad on the bottom or the top of the PCB?

[image]

Comment: You should do a proper calculation to determine if this is the right NMOS for this project. My concern is this: at 10 A and for example 1 V drop across the NMOS it will dissipate 10 Watt. A 50C/W copper plate will not be able to cool the NMOS enough. For 10 A I would consider to use one (or several) NMOS in a larger package that can be mounted on a proper heatsink.

Comment: I was wondering about this actually. I calculated the power dissipation as IxIxRdson = 10*10*12.8mR = 1.28W. Isn’t this correct?

Comment: That calculation is correct **but** to get that 12.8m ohms you have to switch the NMOS **fully on**, I mean, use it as a switch on or off. But in your question you write: *I'm planning to use for a 10A constant current source.* Which made me assume you want to use that NMOS in a circuit like this: http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Current-source-circuit.php (you need to scroll down a bit). In such a circuit the NMOS is not a switch, it **regulates** so it will have a **much higher** resistance than 12.8m ohm and therefore it will also dissipate **a lot** more power.

Comment: The highest Rdson listed in the data sheet is 34.6mR and thats at Vgs =  6V. This translates to a power dissipation of about 3.5W. I think that should be alright with a larger copper pad. It might make sense to connect MOSFETs in parallel as well to share the load.

Comment: *This translates to a power dissipation of about 3.5W* Yes, **but** only if you use the NMOS as a **switch**. It all depends on how you are going to use this NMOS. At the moment you're only looking at the datasheet and the datasheet assumes that you're using this NMOS as a switch. It is designed to be used as a switch. You can use it also use it in a regulator configuration as shown in the schematic from my link above. Then it is **not a switch**. You will need to show a **schematic** of how you intend to use this NMOS. Use it the wrong way and it will overheat and it will break.

Comment: Got it. I plan to use this in an LED driver based on the TPS92640 chip which is essentially a constant current source.

Comment: With the TPS92640 you will be using it in a **buck converter** which is a **switching** converter. Then indeed you will be using the NMOS as a switch and power dissipation should not be very high.

Answer (score 1):

The DS and SS pads are sensing pads, hence the thinner traces compared to the DF and SF pads.

As already mentioned by Bimpelrekkie, the sens lines are used in case you want to measure the voltage drop across your mosfet in case of high currents.
If you don't plan use sens lines, you can connect all drain pins and all source pins together.

Comment: Sensing for what? Does this mean that I need to create a footprint like the one shown in the image?

Comment: Using DS and SS you can measure the voltage across the NMOS while a large current is flowing (through DF and SF) and that large current will then not influence the measurement. If you would measure at DF and SF then you also measure the resistance of the copper. With sense lines you can do a proper **4 point** measurement.

Comment: *Does this mean that I need to create a footprint like the one shown* If you want the 4 point measurement: yes. But if you don't: no. Since you want to make a current source your aim is not a low Ron, the Vds will vary with the current and load. I do not see a reason why you would then need the SF and SS point. So my answer would be no, you do not need to stick to the layout in the image.